# How to check email id existance in java script?

Tags: javascript

I am taking emails id's on input form along with other details like name, address,contact no etc. Now, User can enter any email id's.

e.g. abc@abc.com

I can do check for standard domain whether is it present or not. but Is there any way available to check that email id exist or not?

Is there any API available??

How can i detect wrong email id's.

would be grateful for help...

Comment: If there were a simple API to query mail servers for valid usernames, email as we know it will be crippled by spammers. The standard way to verify email addresses is to send a mail with a unique link which recipients can click to complete the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only valid solution to detect if an email address exists is to send an email and wait for answer.

Most of the times you also want to be sure that your user is the owner of the account, and this solution does both checks.

You can't do this client-side only, you'll need a server-side API. Precise your language (or google "send email yourLanguage").

Answer (score 1):

The way to check is to send a link to that email, user clicking on that link verifies if email is valid or not. Invalid emails won't response of course.

If email is valid and user clicks on the link you send him, you can register him or do any other action you want.